# What do you call the static elements in an interface?

Tags: word-request

[image: diablo]

What do you call the static elements in an interface? By that, I mean, the bottom part which shows you the health and mana and also the top part and the inventory window. What do you call these elements in the user interface, and what do you call the dynamic part that shows the world and the character, and what do you call these two combined (if there's a word for that)?

Comment: I noticed that [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is on-topic at [gaming.se]. I wonder if this question wouldn’t be a better fit there.

Comment: In game design these often have specific names related to their purpose, for example the "inventory **sidebar**" or the "mana/health **bar**".  However these aren't really "static",  as they are continually updated based on the game state.